# HTML - change pattern of date input field

Tags: php, html

I need to change the pattern of the input date field to `Day.Month.Year`, is it possible?

```
<input type="date" name="datum" value="datum"/>
```

Currently it looks like this:

[image]

but if I submit the form and catch the value in PHP then the value is stored like this "2022-02-17"

I found [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) in the firefox documentation, but it does not provide any example.

Answer (score 1):

You could correct the date once you catch the value with your PHP handler.

```
$date = $_POST['datum'];
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));
```

To show date in d.m.Y format in HTML page, again convert it into

```
$date = date("d.m.Y",strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Ok so it is not possible to change the pattern in the input, so that I don't even need to convert it in PHP?

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing with your input. Do you want the value to show one way then submit a different way. Is this a predefined input or does a user enter a value? Either way, you could accomplish this by creating a javascript method to return a value to your input. Your use case would determine if you run the method on change or handle it on submit.

Comment: @Black no, it is not possible. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date tells you that the value is _"A DOMString representing a date in YYYY-MM-DD format, or empty"_ - you need to use that format, if you want to _set_ the value via script, and you will always _get_ that format, when you read it via JS, or submit the form.

Comment: And that `pattern` only _applies_ to the input field types `password`, `text` or `tel` to begin with, you can find mentioned on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attributes

Comment: @CBroe, thx, this is what I wanted to know.